# Regex instead of string.replace function

Tags: c#, regex

I've seen this [CheatSheet for Regex in C#](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

However, I'm trying to create a regex function which can replace this for me:

```
while (fname.Contains(".."))
{
    fname = fname.Replace("..", ".");
}
if (fname.StartsWith(".")) { 
    fname=  fname.Remove(0, 1);
}
fname = fname.Replace("&", "_");
fname = fname.Replace("#", "_");
fname = fname.Replace("{", "_");
fname = fname.Replace("}", "_");
fname = fname.Replace("%", "_");
fname = fname.Replace("~", "_");
fname = fname.Replace("?", "_");
```

I simply don't get how to write the regex which will fix this issue for me.
Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Well what do you expect if you post prematurely!?

Comment: @WillVousden It was added when I hit enter? I was updating it.There was no way for me to show I was updating it.

Comment: Are you sure `fname.Replace("..", ".");` works as you expected?

Comment: Yes, it does.. but I'm still looking for a Regex to solve my issue instead of the replace function :)

Comment: What are you using `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` loop for??

Comment: Why are you looping the first part 10 times?  After 10 you don't care?

Comment: Do you mean `while (fname.Contains("..")) fname = fname.Replace("..", ".");` perhaps?

Comment: Can't see variable `i` being used anywhere?? Then why are you using a for loop??

Comment: This was for testing purposes. I'm looking for a way to use a Regex instead of the loops and the replace functions.

Comment: if you've trouble building your regular expression: [try this for building it](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: @SteffenWinkler sometimes there will be small difference in .net regex and JS. I use http://sharpdev.ru/Regex/Sharp . It's in russian, but you can use google translate

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly so far I had no problems with it, but thanks for the link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string dotsPattern = @"\.\.+"; //2 or more dots.
fname=Regex.Replace(fname, dotsPattern ,".");
String firstSymbolDot = @"^\.";
fname = Regex.Replace(fname, firstSymbolDot, String.Empty);
string symbolPattern = "[&#{}%~?]"; //any of given symbol;
string result = Regex.Replace(fname, symbolPattern, "_");
```

Comment: You're not using symbolPattern now, but I know it should be behind Replace(fname, symbolPattern,"_");
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping over `fname=fname.Replace("..", ".");`, are you trying to replace all sequences of more than one dot with just one dot?

That's:

```
fname=Regex.Replace(fname,@"\.+",".");
```

As for the others:

```
fname=Regex.Replace(
    Regex.Replace(
        fname,
        @"&|\#|\{|\}|%|~|\?",
        "_"
    ),
    @"^\.",
    ""
);
```